# What is the difference between pointer in Fortran and a C++

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran

I have written a subroutine package in Fortran 95/08 that is used in a simulation written in C++ with the iso_c binding.  I note that one has to call a routine, c_loc, to convert a Fortran pointer to a C++ one.  Why?  What does this do?  I understand it makes it possible for the C++ program to axcess data within the record the pointer but what is a pointer more than an address?

Bo Sundman

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing

Comment: Might have to do with the way pointers on Fortran/C++ are compiled and assembled

Comment: F08 provides for c interoperability with Fortran pointers, descriptors and all.   C_LOC gives you an integer or "Cray" pointer which could be interoperable with c pointer.

Comment: `c_loc()` provides a `c_ptr`, not an integer pointer. `loc()` gives an integer pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran pointer can be often implemented as just an address. In many cases (non-polymorphic scalars) `c_loc()` on a Fortran pointer to create a C pointer is just a cast, nothing more. The same for `c_f_pointer()`, it is just a cast for non-polymorphic scalars.

For polymorphic entities Fortran pointers carry information about the dynamic type.

For arrays Fortran pointers contain the array descriptor which store the address of the first element, the rank, the lower and the upper bounds in each dimension and the strides. That's why you have to specify the dimensions in `c_f_pointers()` for arrays.

Fortran pointer arrays may be non-contiguous, e.g., just a subsection of a larger array. There is no equivalent for non-contiguous array pointers in C.

It has nothing to do with pointer aliasing. Fortran pointers are allowed to alias. Non-pointer dummy arguments are not allowed to alias.